# Theme a subscriber field in Simplenews issues

Tags: theming

I need to address my subscribers in a more personal way. Thus I added fields for Mr./Mrs., firstname, lastname to the subscription block, and data gets collected nicely.
However, I can't see how to theme these fields in simplenews-newsletter-body.html.twig.

In the header of this template there's an example printing the subscriber's (built-in) mail.

```
 {{ simplenews_subscriber.getMail  }}
```

Trying the same as `{{ simplenews_subscriber.field_lastname  }}` doesn't do anything. I tried a lot of variations to this approach, but to no avail.

What's the secret of getting custom subscriber fields to print with Twig?

Comment: Have you looked at the original *simplenews-newsletter-body* template. Usually a template has documentation at the top of the file that specifies which variables are available, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, and yes, I themed simplenews since Drupal 6, but I don't get the TWIG way to access custom fields. Built-in fields are covered by the .get<Variable> method, which doesn't work for me (the way I try it, at least). I can see all the variables I created dumping the simplemail_subscriber variable, but I'm totally clueless as of how to access these from my twig code.

Answer (score 0):

{{ simplenews_subscriber.field_lastname.value }}

In the header of this template:

> Note that depending on the used caching strategy, the generated body
> might be used for multiple subscribers. If you created personalized
> newsletters and can't use tokens for that, make sure to disable
> caching or write a custom caching strategy implemention.

To solve it I added in the sites/default/services.yml

```
services:
  simplenews.mail_cache: ~
  
  simplenews.mail_cache:
    class: Drupal\simplenews\Mail\MailCacheNone
```

Comment: Hi @cuman, welcome to Drupal Answers. You seem to be quoting something, but you haven't sourced your quote.